# Как вывести через API битрикс свойство элемента каждого товара - "цвет"? (товар принадлежит торговым предложениям)

Tags: битрикс

Пробую используя API Битрикс на примере встроенного шаблона интернет магазина вывести товар и рядом в таблице его цвет, но видимо что то не до конца понимаю, подскажите где может быть неточность?

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {

    $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_*");

    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 2, "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y", "ACTIVE" => "Y");

    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
                    Array("NAME" => "ASC"), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 100), $arSelect
    );



    echo "<table id=\"mid\" border = 1>";
    while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<td>";

        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        print_r($arFields["NAME"]);
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        print_r($arProps["COLOR"]["VALUE"]);
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

При этом 1й столбик выводится нормально со списком товаров, а второй столбик пуст. Документацию читал, не помогло понять. Спасибо.

Comment: в arSelect укажите именно код свойства к которому вы обращаетесь, а не PROPERTY_*, например PROPERTY_COLOR

Comment: Я первым делом это попробовал сделать, но ничего в таблице не изменилось.

Comment: а какой именно код у нужного Вам свойства?

Comment: Если речь идет о коде, который находится в Магазин-Каталоги товаров-Одежда-Свойства торговых предложений, то код цвета там COLOR_REF

Comment: Оставьте arSelect пустым.

Comment: сделайте print_r($arProps), чтобы понять, какие данные туда приходят.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос. Вывести свойства элемента не получалось потому, что я выбрал неверный "IBLOCK_ID" => 2. Этот блок принадлежал обычным товарам, без торговых предложений. Как только я это понял, я начал искать нужный мне инфоблок, отвечающий за ТП. Им, по умолчанию шаблона, оказался "IBLOCK_ID" => 3. Спасибо всем, кто мне помогал разобраться )